# Can I bring an electric hair clipper in my hand luggage?

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage

I have a [hair clipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_clipper#/media/File:PB070062_chousei.jpg) that I want to take with me abroad so I can trim my beard (and look closer to my passport photo).

Is it generally permitted to take such machine in my hand luggage? Specifically this one is portable and presumably fully charged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, they're permitted, I always travel with mine in carry-on and have never had a single question about it.  The blades in the cutting head are tiny and it's completely useless as a weapon.

Pro tip: Do consider removing the batteries or securing the on/off switch, or it may turn on by itself at awkward times (a buzzing bag will get inspected!) and/or drain the batteries.

Comment: Ah, that is good advice about the batteries. Brings to mind Fight Club "a dildo" scene.

Comment: @Inkblot [youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZVd659gxd0)